# How to get groups similar to the "findall" command in re module in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

As we know, the "search" command returns a match object.

```
mystring= 'string with numbers 990'
my_obj = re.search('(.{1}[h0])',mystring)
```

I'd like to be able to print the list of matching strings, similar to the `findall` method. I tried `my_obj.groups()`, but this still only prints the first matching object:

```
findall_result = re.findall('(.{1}[h0])',mystring)

>>> findall_result
['th', '90']
>>> my_obj.groups()
('th',)
>>>
```

How do I return all of the matching strings from a match object like the `findall` does?

Comment: what's wrong with findall? search return only the first match.

Comment: this is a piece of much larger code.  the inputs in that code are match objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
You could use mo.group(), not groups. mo.group(1) with refer
 to the first bracketed group and so on. but mo.group(0) to 
 the whole string match.

s = "somethingabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeabcdeelseabcdeabcdeabcde"

mo = re.search(r"(abc)d(ea)", s)

print(mo.group(0))
#abcdea
print(mo.group(1))
# abc
print(mo.group(2))
# ea

 mystring= 'string with numbers 990'

mo = re.search(r'(\wg\s).*\s(\d\d)\d',mystring)

print(mo.group(0))
# ng with numbers 990
print(mo.group(1))
# ng
print(mo.group(2))
# 99
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me.  It still only returns the first match.

Comment: @Candic3    what is your string, and what are you trying to match?

Comment: `mystring= 'string with numbers 990' ;
my_obj = re.search('(.{1}[h0])',mystring) ;
print my_obj.group(1) ;
print my_obj.group(2) ;` .....and I get `no such group` error when I try to print the second one.  First one prints `'th'`, as expected.

Comment: @Candic3 you have no second group. groups are counted in re.search or re.match  when in brackets, to have a second group you have to have a second group of () and a regex inside.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `finditer`:

```
print [m.group(0) for m in re.finditer('(.{1}[h0])',mystring)]
```